# Toplink xml descriptor reference

Tags: oracle, file-descriptor, toplink

I am very new to Toplink.
And new to the current project, that I am maintaining.

The project has a 1 MB file size project descriptor (xml project descriptor).
When I open it with Toplink workbench, it takes 10 minutes.
the other developer who is older than me, told me that he is not using workbench, but modifying the descriptor with any xml editor (just notepad++).

But there are no reference for toplink using xml descriptor.
All tutorial and documentation are for using the workbench, and modifying through UI and then save it to xml.

do you know any reference for toplink for its xml descriptor?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XML schema XSD for the project.xml as a reference, or the examples provided in an install.

The XSD should be in a /xsd directory in your TopLink install.

The EclipseLink XSDs for project.xml are similar, you can see them here,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/XSDs